# When reading a JSON string in java for Android it is giving the error No value found when there is a value to find for "name"

Tags: android, json, android-studio

My Json :

```
{ 
   "location":{ 
      "name":"Chennai",
      "region":"Tamil Nadu",
      "country":"India",
      "lat":13.08,
      "lon":80.28,
      "tz_id":"Asia/Kolkata",
      "localtime_epoch":1579921744,
      "localtime":"2020-01-25 8:39"
   },
   "current":{ 
      "last_updated_epoch":1579921212,
      "last_updated":"2020-01-25 08:30",
      "temp_c":22.0,
      "temp_f":71.6,
      "is_day":1,
      "condition":{ 
         "text":"Mist",
         "icon":"//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/143.png",
         "code":1030
      },
      "wind_mph":0.0,
      "wind_kph":0.0,
      "wind_degree":0,
      "wind_dir":"N",
      "pressure_mb":1016.0,
      "pressure_in":30.5,
      "precip_mm":0.0,
      "precip_in":0.0,
      "humidity":94,
      "cloud":25,
      "feelslike_c":24.6,
      "feelslike_f":76.2,
      "vis_km":2.0,
      "vis_miles":1.0,
      "uv":5.0,
      "gust_mph":6.5,
      "gust_kph":10.4
   }
}
```

My code

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                String name = jsonObject.getString("location");

            Log.i("Weather Details" , name);

            String cityname = jsonObject.getString("name");

            Log.i("cityname", cityname);

            String message = "";


            if (!message.equals("")) {
                resultTextView.setText(message);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "couldn't find the giberish you mentioned :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

My error :

> 0-01-25 09:28:41.037 16028-16028/com.example.myjson I/Weather Details: {"name":"Goa","region":"Goa","country":"India","lat":15.4,"lon":73.8,"tz_id":"Asia/Kolkata","localtime_epoch":1579924225,"localtime":"2020-01-25 9:20"}
>
> 2020-01-25 09:28:41.037 16028-16028/com.example.myjson W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for name
>
> 2020-01-25 09:28:41.037 16028-16028/com.example.myjson W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "name" property is inside the "location" one. You're looking for it on the root. Try changing this:

```
String cityname = jsonObject.getString("name");
```

To this:

```
String cityname = jsonObject.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because name is inside location tag and you are trying to get name directly from main json object .You should try following solution.

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonString);

        String location = jsonObject.getString("location");

        JSONObject jsonObject1=new JSONObject(location);
        String name=jsonObject1.getString("name");

        Log.i("TAG", "cityName: "+name);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("TAG", ": ",e );
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`````
    ````
    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    super.onPostExecute(s);

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

            String name = jsonObject.getString("location");


        Log.i("Weather Details" , name);

        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(name);
        String cityname = jsonObject1.getString("name");

        Log.i("cityname", cityname);
        String message = "";


        if (!message.equals("")) {
            resultTextView.setText(message);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "couldn't find the giberish you mentioned :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
`````

```
try this
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on Post Execute

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(s);
JSONObject location = reader.getJSONObject("location");
String name = location.getString("name");
```